# An exception "flutter: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'" is thrown when formatting json data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fetch and format json data from [this](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2) as a trial in flutter. However, during the formatting process, an exception occurs: `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'`.

And these are my code:

user_model.dart

```
class User {
  int    id;
  String email;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String avator;
  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.avator
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    id        : json['id'],
    email     : json['email'],
    firstName : json['first_name'],
    lastName  : json['last_name'],
    avator    : json['avator']
  );
}
```

user_api.dart

```
...
class UserApi {
  Future<List<User>?> getUsers() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2');
    try {
      final res = await http.get(url);
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        final Map<String, dynamic> body  = jsonDecode(res.body);
        final List<User> users = body['data'].map((dynamic userData) => {
          print('userData : $userData');
          User.fromJson(userData) // There seems to be an error here.
        }).toList();
        return users;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And `userData` seems like this in my console:

```
flutter: userData : {id: 7, email: michael.lawson@reqres.in, first_name: Michael, last_name: Lawson, avatar: https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg}
```

I don't think userData is kind of `Null`, but why do I get the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `json['avatar']`  instead of `json['avator']`

```dart
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
    id        : json['id'],
    email     : json['email'],
    firstName : json['first_name'],
    lastName  : json['last_name'],
    avator    : json['avatar'] //here `a` instead of `o`
  );
```

Comment: Oh I'm embarrassed... Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help, also I prefer using nullable Datatype on null safety it is `String?`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the [link](https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2) you have mentioned for the json you are using. There is a typo at your end. In the json, `avatar` is the correct field spelling. You have mentioned `avator` in your class's factory constructor.

So, `avator` is `Null` and thus, `String avator` is assigned to a `Null` value.

FYI: The error `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'` means that you are trying to assign a `Null` value to a `String` type variable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and useful information! I chose the answer I received earliest as the best one, but this also helps me a lot. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

its a typo in the fromJson method : as mentioned by yeasin-sheikh (You need to use json['avatar'] instead of json['avator']),
[Yeasin-sheikh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319530/7159206)

there are some json parsing websites, using that we can easily generate model class and other methods related to it.

eg : [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io)

just input the json response and generate the model class in required language.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer and useful information! Since I am a novice in developing systems, it would be very helpful to learn about such features. I chose the answer I received earliest as the best one, but this also helps me a lot. I really appreciate it.